# What do I need to do in order to push a behind branch

Tags: git

I have pushed up to B to Github. I realized something is wrong so I reset to A(61d4b9cb) by `git reset --hard 61d4b9cb`.

```
remote       --o---o---A---B
                        \
local                    C
```

Now I made changed (in the same files as I did in B) and committed as C. Now when I push C to Github, I get the following errors.

```
To https://github.com/myname/repoame.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
...
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

I hesitate to pull since it will change my files again (may be I am wrong).
What do I need to do in order to push C? I want to make it something like this.

```
--o---o---A---C

or

--o---o---A---B--C
```

Comment: You apparently pushed C before. You have two choices. Pull from C and merge in what you pushed, or push -f and erase it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git push -f` will allow you to overwrite the history in the repository and leave `--o---o---A---C`. The caveat is that if someone has pulled from repository while `B` existed there, they will end up in a situation similar to yours and `B` may be resurrected when they push back to the repository.

Your other option would be `git rebase` of `C` on top of `B`. That should give you `-o---o---A---B--C1` where `C1` will contain changes necessary to turn `B` into `C`. Git will then allow you to push `C1` upstream.

Another option is to checkout `B` and then `git cherry-pick C`. In this case it would be equivalent to manual `git rebase` of `C` on top of `B`.

Answer (score 2):

I would not choose `git push -f` as you lost the development history of that mistake. How about doing either of followings to correct commits?

Option 1: Revert the wrong commit, create a good commit C'

```
git revert ${commit_A}
git cherry-pick ${commit_C} # Commit C becomes another commit C'
git push origin HEAD:refs/heads/master # You push commit C' instead of C on top of the reverted A
```

Option 2: Forcefully bring C' code state

```
git checkout ${commit_C}
git reset --soft ${commit_B} # Going to commit B without changing the local code
git commit # Create commit C'
git push origin HEAD:refs/heads/master # Again, you push commit C' instead of C
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `-f` flag to do a force push. Ex:

```
git push -f origin master
```

Beware that force push can be dangerous and meddles with the history.